# how to tell Python that we always want to interpret an object of type Foo as an object of type Bar when there are conflicts?

Tags: python, coercion

I am a novice, so please excuse non-standard terminology and let me know if I should add code to make this question more clear.

Let's say that we try to make a class "Rational" in Python. (I know that one is already built in, but ignore that for the purpose of this question.)

We can use `__add__` and `__mul__`, for example, to teach Python how to interpret code of the form `a + b` or `a * b`,

where `a` and `b` are Rationals.

Now, it may happen that, somewhere else, one wants to compute `a + b`, where `a` is a rational but `b` is an integer. This we can do by modifying our `__add__` code within the Rational class to include an if statement, for instance,

```
def __add__(self, b):
    if isinstance(b, int):
        brat = rational(b, 1)
        return self + brat
    else:
        y = rational(self.num*b.den + b.num*self.den , b.den*self.den)
        y = y.lowest_terms()
        return y
```

We can similarly modify our `__mul__` code, our `__div__` code, etc. But there are at least two problems with this kind of solution:

1. It only works when the second argument is an `int`. The first
   argument still has to be a Rational; there's no way to write a
   method in the Rational class that allows us to add `a + b` where a is
   an int and be is a Rational.
2. It's repetitive. What we really want is some technique be able to
   say once, globally, in some way, "whenever you are trying to do an
   operation on multiple objects, some of which are Rationals and some
   of which are integers, treat the integers as Rationals by mapping n
   to Rational(n, 1)."

Does such a technique exist? (I have tagged this coercion because I think this is what's called coercion in other contexts, but my understanding is that coercion is deprecated in Python.)

Comment: comment on 1.: there is [`__radd__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) (and similiar) that you can implement for your `Rationals` such that `integer+rational` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the repetition by doing the mapping in the class's initializer. Here's a simple demo that handles integers. Handling `float`s properly will be left as an exercise for the reader. :) However, I *have* shown how to easily implement `__radd__`, and `__iadd__`, which is the magic method (aka [dunder](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200605/dunder.html) method) that handles `+=`.

My code retains `rational` from your code as the class name, even though class names in Python are conventionally CamelCase.

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b > 0:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a

class rational(object):
    def __init__(self, num, den=1):
        if isinstance(num, rational):
            self.copy(num)
        else:
            self.num = num
            self.den = den

    def copy(self, other):
        self.num = other.num 
        self.den = other.den

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} / {1}'.format(self.num, self.den)

    def lowest_terms(self):
        g = gcd(self.num, self.den)
        return rational(self.num // g, self.den // g)

    def __add__(self, other):
        other = rational(other)
        y = rational(self.num*other.den + other.num*self.den, other.den*self.den)
        return y.lowest_terms()

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return rational(other) + self

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.copy(self + rational(other))
        return self


a = rational(1, 4)
b = rational(2, 5)
c = a + b
print a
print b
print c
print c + 5
print 10 + c
c += 10
print c
```

**output**

```
1 / 4
2 / 5
13 / 20
113 / 20
213 / 20
213 / 20
```

You may like to reserve that `copy` method for internal use; the usual convention is to prepend such names with a single underscore.

Comment: 'dunder'?! never heard of it. love it!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of coercing the arguments, a more general approach would be for you could make create your own *multimethods* module, similar to that described in the article titled [*Five-minute Multimethods in Python*](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605) written several years ago by Guido van Rossum. This would allow you to avoid a lot of repetitive code. Here's a version of it to enhanced to support "associative_multimethod" functions that accept their arguments in reverse order:

```
# This is in the 'mm' module

_registry = {}

class MultiMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.typemap = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        types = tuple(arg.__class__ for arg in args)
        function = self.typemap.get(types)
        if function is None:
            raise TypeError("no match")
        return function(*args)
    def register(self, types, function):
        if types in self.typemap:
            raise TypeError("duplicate registration")
        print('registering: {!r} for args: {}'.format(function.__name__, types))
        self.typemap[types] = function

def multimethod(*types):
    def register(function):
        name = function.__name__
        mm = _registry.get(name)
        if mm is None:
            mm = _registry[name] = MultiMethod(name)
        mm.register(types, function)
        return mm
    return register

def associative_multimethod(*types):
    def register(function):
        name = function.__name__
        mm = _registry.get(name)
        if mm is None:
            mm = _registry[name] = MultiMethod(name)
        mm.register(types[::-1], lambda a, b: function(b, a))
        mm.register(types, function)
        return mm
    return register
```

This would allow you write code like this:

```
from mm import associative_multimethod, multimethod

class Rational(object):
    pass

@multimethod(int, int)
def foo(a, b):
    print('...code for two ints...')

@associative_multimethod(int, Rational)
def foo(a, b):
    print('...code for int and Rational...')

@multimethod(Rational, Rational)
def foo(a, b):
    print('...code two Rationals...')

a, b, c, d = 1, 2, Rational(), Rational()

foo(a, b)
foo(a, c)
foo(c, a)
foo(c, d)
```